# File name with DateTime stamp

Tags: log4net

I have the following RollingFileAppender config:

```xml
  <appender name="appender.VTBGPRS" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <file value="mylog" />
    <staticLogFileName value="false" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

And I have files named mylog, mylog.1, mylog.2, etc.
I want to add date time stamp to the file name. For example mylog-2012-07.

I can't use datePattern because rollingStyle is set to Size.

How can I add date time stamp to the file name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rollingStyle` as `Composite`. It will split logs base on size and date.

```
  <appender name="appender.VTBGPRS" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
    <datePattern value="-yyyyMMdd'.txt'" />
    <file value="mylog" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="20" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %logger{1} - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
```

This will generate logs as: `myLog.1, mylog.2, ...` **during current day** and they will be changed to `myLog-20141024.txt.1, myLog-20141024.txt.2, ...` **at the end of the day**. You can try it by changing system date to the future to see this log rolling mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change things at runtime, you can use something like:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{FileName}" />
```

And in code:

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["FileName"] = somethingWithADateInIt;
```

and format the somethingWithADateInIt string using whatever is relevant in your language.